# How can I log in/sign up a user using React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, authentication, react-hooks

I'm making a React Native app which doesn't involve user interaction with other users but requires the user to have an account with all of their info.

I am currently just assigning the user to a variable which at least stores their information for me to use in other parts of the app, but I wanted to find a tool that could store all of the users and do things like authenticate or log in properly.

This is the code for the Log In component (I removed the styles for better understanding):

```
// User information
const [user, setUser] = useState({
 name: "",
 email: "",
 password: ""
});
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, SetPassword] = useState("");

// Capitalize user's name
const capitalizeName = (name) => {
 return name
  .toLowerCase()
  .split(' ')
  .map((word) => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
  .join(' ');
};

// Handle submit information
const handleSubmit = (name, email, password, passwordAgain) => {
 if (!name || !email || !password) {
  alert("All fiels are required");

 } else {
  setUser({
   name: name,
   email: email,
   password: password
  });
  return user;
 }
}

const Login = () => {
 return (
  <View>
   <Text>
    Log In to have the best experience!
   </Text>
    
   <View>
    <TextInput name="name" value={name} placeholder={"Full Name"} autoCorrect={false} onSubmitEditing={(event) => setName(capitalizeName(event.nativeEvent.text))}/>
    <TextInput name="email" value={email} placeholder={"Email"} autoCorrect={false} onSubmitEditing={(event) => setEmail(event.nativeEvent.text.toLowerCase())}/>
    <TextInput name="password" value={password} placeholder={"New password"} autoCorrect={false} onSubmitEditing={(event) => setPassword(event.nativeEvent.text)}/>
    <TouchableOpacity style={} onPress={() => handleSubmit(name, email, password, passwordAgain)}>Log in</TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
              
   <View>
    <Link href="/components/common/ForgotPassword">
     Forgot Password?
    </Link>
   </View>

   <View>
    <Text>
     I'm a new user.{" "}
    </Text>
    <Link href="/components/common/ForgotPassword">
     Sign up
    </Link>
   </View>
  </View>
 )
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want OAuth2. Check this blog https://alexmngn.medium.com/the-essential-boilerplate-to-authenticate-users-on-your-react-native-app-f7a8e0e04a42